# achemso package: TOC entry behaves strangely

Tags: table-of-contents, achemso

I am trying to write a manuscript for J. Phys. Chem. Lett. using the `achemso` package. But I am encountering a strange problem with the TOC entry (defined by `\begin{tocentry} ... \end{tocentry}`) when I use the `journal=jpclcd` class option. With `journal=jacsat`, the TOC entry gets printed in a separate page at the very end as documented. But if I use `journal=jpclcd` the TOC entry is printed just after the Abstract.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[journal=jpclcd,manuscript=letter,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}

\title{This is my title}
\author{Unknown Author}
\affiliation{Unknown University, Unknown Town}

\begin{tocentry}
This box and the associated title will always be printed on a separate page at the end of the document.
\end{tocentry}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is my abstract.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Also, not using the `tocentry` section leads to the following very confusing error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...@tocentry@width {\acs@tocentry@text 
                                                  }\end {minipage}
l.132 \end{abstract}
```

Here is a minimum working example to reproduce this error:

```
\documentclass[journal=jpclcd,manuscript=letter,layout=twocolumn]{achemso}

\title{This is my title}
\author{Unknown Author}
\affiliation{Unknown University, Unknown Town}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is my abstract.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion regarding how to workaround this issue for `journal=jpclcd` would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like my fault! Logged as https://github.com/josephwright/achemso/issues/18: will aim to fix today.

Answer (score 2):

The first 'issue' is by-design. The [official submissions guidelines](http://pubs.acs.org/paragonplus/submission/jpchax/jpclcd_authguide.pdf) say

> Abstract, Table of Contents Image, and Keywords (in this order, preferably on a single page)

As a result, [I altered the position of the TOC graphic](https://github.com/josephwright/achemso/commit/ebaad2c96221e9056a579ec2d84bb6db7189c4fd) for this publication.

In terms of the second issue, I will add a line to the next release to make sure something more sensible happens here. However, you still need to define the TOC entry in some way. I'm therefore not going to send to CTAN at this stage: this issue can I think wait until the next style change I need to make.